# How should I troubleshoot a refrigerator that is not cooling?

Tags: repair, appliances, refrigerator

I am having an issue with an 3 month old Frigidaire refrigerator. Suddenly today, I noticed it was not cooling, there were no circuit breakers flipped and the unit was still running but just not blowing cold air.

The coils are clean the condenser is not super hot. The fan that circulates the air and the fan for the coils are both running. I believe the compressor is also running because it is warm to the touch.

One thing I can notice is that the coils are not really hot, and the copper wire coming out of the compressor is not cold (it is cool though).

My first thought was, is it stuck on defrost? But since the fans are running I don't think so. Then I thought maybe something is wrong with the overload or start capacitor, but since it appears that the compressor is running (since it is getting warm), I'm not sure if that logic is sound though.

Just a note I do not have a volt meter so I cannot test if the start or overload relay are working.

Thoughts on troubleshooting or should I just call a repair man?

Comment: Three months old? Call service (assuming you confirmed that the temperature settings inside the unit have not been turned to *off*).

Comment: Have you ever tried calling Frigidaire customer support? It is abysmal, I just tried calling (7:45 am PST) and the message says please call back during our office hours Monday-Saturday 8am-8pm EST. The fridge came with the house, so since I am not the original purchaser I don't even know if they will help me.

Comment: Yep - Should be covered under warranty. Don't mess with it yourself and possibly void that. Try the local dealer if the national service is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the freezer side is working. Often times the cold air comes from the freezer side via vents/holes going from the freezer to the fridge which can be adjusted. If the freezer side is working and the fridge isn't, it's likely these are completely closed or maybe blocked by items in the freezer covering them.

This may not be your exact issue. But, I'm adding it as an answer because I'm sure it will be the source of the problem for many others.